# How to find configuration that wil emulate specific network conditions with netem / tc?

Tags: linux, networking, wan, emulation, packet-loss

We had our otherwise well tested application fail once it was deployed on a device connected via a poor wan connection.

To be able to debug this we want to *reproduce the bad network conditions in a controlled environment*. We decided to use the `tc` / [`netem`](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) tools to build a dedicated "bad network box" as outlined in [this](http://tdistler.com/2011/06/10/netem-wan-emulation-how-to-setup-a-netem-box) article.

So the documentation is really good on how to reproduce all sorts of network problems like **low bandwidth**, **high latency**, **packet reordering**, **packet loss** and even **packet corruption**.

What we don't find any documentation for is how to properly select values for testing to reproduce some specific conditions that we experience in our live environment. So my question is: **How can we evaluate the network conditions in our live environment to come up with good configuration values for netem/ tc that we can use to emulate said live conditions?**

If it matters we are on Debian x64 platform.

Any tools, scripts, tips & tricks are welcome!

Comment: How about going to the (or another)  poor wireless environment and measuring the latency, bandwidth and packet loss? Then you plug those values into your test network

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Search for "measure latency bandwidth packet loss" and do some research.